# Image processing with C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, jpeg

I have a college assignment where I need to do basic image processing such as opening an image, re-sampling, scaling and some pixel connectivity based operations.

Is there any library to make things easier such as jpg viewing and enabling pixel level accessing? Will OpenCV be a good option if so what are the libraries that I should be using?

(I do not want to directly call library methods to do them as this assignment needs to be done some what manually)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at imagemagick

Comment: openCV is very optimized and often not intuitive for beginners (e.g. how to access pixels), so maybe it's not the best thing to use for your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use ImageMagick to convert your images to PBM/PGM or PNM format (as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)) then you can easily read the images in in C++ and write them out in the same, very easy format which is just

```
P1 (or P2-P6)
width height (in ASCII text)
pixel pixel pixel pixel ...
pixel pixel pixel pixel ...
```

That way you can concentrate on the image processing and pixel connectivity rather than worrying about run-length encoding, palettes or JPEG DCTs etc.

To convert a JPEG to PNM just use ImageMagick's `convert` tool

```
convert image.jpg image.pnm
```

or a TIF to PPM

```
convert image.tif image.ppm
```

If you want NetPBM formats P1-P3 which have ASCII pixel data rather than binary, use the option `-compression none` with ImageMagick's `convert` command, i.e.

```
convert image.jpg -compresssion none image.pnm
```

whereas if you want NetPBM formats P4-P6, with binary pixel data, leave off the `-compression none` parameter:

```
convert image.jpg image.pnm
```