# C++ Best way to read BitMap "Right Way up" into 1D Vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, bitmap, array-algorithms

I am trying to read a BitMap "The Right Way Up" into a 1D Vector.  Here is my first attempt.  It is pretty clunky:

```
void BitMap::ReadBMP(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "rb");
if(f == NULL)
    throw "Argument Exception";

unsigned char info[54];
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

// extract image height and width from header
m_width = *(int*)&info[18];
m_height = *(int*)&info[22];

cout << endl;
cout << "  Name: " << filename << endl;
cout << " Width: " << m_width << endl;
cout << "Height: " << m_height << endl;

int row_padded = (m_width*3 + 3) & (~3);
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char[row_padded];
unsigned char tmp;

std::deque<Element> mydeque;
std::vector<Element> bmpRow;

for(int i = 0; i < m_height; i++)
{
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), row_padded, f);
    for(int j = 0; j < m_width*3; j += 3)
    {
                    // BGRA format
        Element element;
        element.Elements[0] = data[j+2];
        element.Elements[1] = data[j+1];
        element.Elements[2] = data[j];
        element.Elements[3] = 0; // for alpha
        bmpRow.push_back(element);
    }
    mydeque.insert (mydeque.begin(),bmpRow.begin(),bmpRow.end());
    bmpRow.clear();
}

std::copy(mydeque.begin(), mydeque.end(), std::back_inserter(m_pixelVec)); 
cout<< "After Deque Copy" << endl;

fclose(f);
delete data;
```

}

Problem is, I need to iterate through the data at a different point of the APP like this - note h and W swapped for setPixel.  **Please ignore this part, this is just to demonstrate the BitMap needs to be rotated in C++ part above:**

```
for (int h = 0; h<imageHeight; h++)
{
    for (int w = 0; w<imageWidth; w++)
    {
        int p = 0;
        Pixel pixel = currentImagePixelVec.get(pixelVecLoc);
        p = (pixel.Alpha<<24) | (pixel.Red<<16) | (pixel.Green<<8) | pixel.Blue;                
        imageData.setPixel(w, h, p);            
        pixelVecLoc++;
    }
}
```

So I would like to rotate the BitMap as I read it into the 1D Vector.  Can you suggest a good way?

**EDIT:**
This is really just for testing purposes. I am only using BitMaps I know the height and width of etc.. I would like to know from an algorithm point of view how people would do it

Comment: You may like to let ImageMagick convert BMP, PNG, JPG, TIF, GIF and so on into NetPBM format so you can read/write any format with about 8 lines of code... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24599122/2836621

Comment: Just use `imageHeight - 1 - h` to invert the y coordinate.

Comment: @JonathanPotter My preference is to fix it when I read it in in C++

Comment: Don't. Simply don't. The BMP file format is radically more complex than you think. Use a library instead.

Comment: @IInspectable *most* BMP files aren't all that complex, which is what makes the format so appealing. But that just means that you won't run into one of the complex ones during testing, only at some much more inconvenient time later. Your advice to use a library is a good one, although for *writing* a BMP file you may be able to get by without one.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Even for 'standard' bitmaps there are several gotchas (DWORD-alignment for scanlines is one that most developers get wrong). And even writing BMP's to disk poses several obstacles (the number of entries in the color palette is a common source of confusion). Using a library or even system services (e.g. [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx)) is recommended either way.

Comment: http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to transpose the image data; that is, store columns of pixels in contiguous segments of m_pixelVec, rather than rows.

It seems to me that the easiest way to do this is by placing values into a 2D data structure as they are read, then flattening it. That makes it trivial to change column-major vs row-major order, by just flipping the indices.

To access any point when I want, without any push_backs, I preallocated the whole thing, which assumes the Element type is default-constructible. I used a vector of vectors, but a 2D array could work just as well.

I noticed that you put the first row read (i == 0) at the end of your vector and assumed you want to keep that behavior. Hence the index `m_height-i-1` when assigning to `bmpcolrow`.
Another possibility is to just use `bmpcolrow[j][i]` and then reverse the columns when inserting (use `col.rbegin()` and `col.rend()` in the last line).

```
std::vector<std::vector<Element>> bmpcolrow(m_width, std::vector<Element>(m_height));

for(int i = 0; i < m_height; i++) {
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), row_padded, f);
    for(int j = 0; j < m_width; j++) {
                // BGRA format
        Element element;
        element.Elements[0] = data[3*j+2];
        element.Elements[1] = data[3*j+1];
        element.Elements[2] = data[3*j];
        element.Elements[3] = 0; // for alpha
        bmpcolrow[j][m_height-i-1] = element;
    }
}

for (const auto& col : bmpcolrow)
    m_pixelVec.insert(m_pixelVec.end(), col.begin(), col.end());
```